# Face book integration with cordova android application Key Hash issue

Tags: facebook, cordova

I am using ccsoft cordova facebook plugin to integrate facebook app in my cordova android application. The code runs fine at one stage and next time whe ever i run the code is gives me Key hash error again it runs without any change and so on what may be the reson. I have deleed app from facebook for number of times but the issues remains the same.

Comment: Try to be a bit more precise to someone could help you. For example, post the concerning code and the error with stacktrace you get.

Comment: Solved This issue by creating only one key with new keystore

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by creating new key value using a fixed Android Key store. Create entire new Keystore file using unsigned method for creation of apk